# Git filter tag is not working for multiple pattern

Tags: git

As per the document,

```
Running "git tag" without arguments also lists all tags. The pattern is a shell wildcard (i.e., matched using fnmatch(3)). Multiple patterns may be given; if any of them matches, the tag is shown.
```

there are multiple tags in the repository and I want to list out only two sets of pattern in Jenkins git params.

Jenkins Git Parameter plugins are used to filter the "git tag -l {pattern}" and the pattern is based on fnmatch.

Example tag 
DEV2.3.4
ST2.4.6
SIT2.1.6

I just to filter out the DEV and ST tag. I tried a few different patterns.

`git tag -l '(?:ST|DEV)\*'$/`

`git tag -l '/^DEV[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*$/'`

`git tag -l '@(DEV*|ST*)'`

Could you help me out?

Comment: Hint: `glob/fnmatch` don't implement logical OR. If you can you should run 2 separate commands: `git tag -l '@DEV*'` and `git tag -l '@ST*'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crucial part of your quote above is:

> The pattern is a shell wildcard (i.e., matched using fnmatch(3)).

Shell wildcards match with `*`, `?`, and `[...]` only.<sup>1</sup>  They are implicitly rooted at both ends.  For instance, the pattern `a*z` matches `abcz`, `axyz`, and `az` but not `azy` (doesn't *end* with `z`) nor `baz` (doesn't *start* with `a`).  In shell wildcard patterns, question marks match any character, asterisks match zero or more of any character, and bracketed expressions match those characters.  You can get all the `DEV`s with `DEV*`, and all the `ST`s with `ST*`, but there is no syntax to match both.

---

<sup>1</sup>The C library `fnmatch` function takes flags that modify its behavior, and on systems with a GNU fnmatch, you can get some extended forms including the `@(pattern1|pattern2)` you were attempting.  But Git doesn't set the flag that enables this.

Answer (score 1):

As @torek already notes: A 'regex' is not a 'pattern' (aka. 'glob'). But you can emulate the OR (`|`) of a regex using multiple pattern because

> [...] Multiple patterns may be given; if any of them matches, the tag is shown.

So this would select both `DEV*` and `ST*` tags:

```
git tag --list 'DEV*' 'ST*'
```